# How to optimize linq for grouping and sorting

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have searched the archives but can't find a solution to this. I am trying to simply group a collection of entities by **UniqueId**, then sort by **RevisionNumber** and return the entity with the highest RevisionNumber for each UniqueId.

So for the sample data,

```
[UniqueId, RevisionNumber]

[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
```

The resulting collection would return

```
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
```

Does anyone see how to combine the two statements below into a single linq query that sorts the collection, groups it, and returns the projected DTO object for only the highest revision for each unique id?

Thanks!

```
private static IEnumerable<RevisionDto> ExtractHighestRevisions(IEnumerable<RevisionEntity> revisions)
{
    var groupedRevisions = (from r in revisions
                orderby r.RevisionNumber descending
                group r by r.UniqueId
                    into grp
                    select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.RevisionNumber).FirstOrDefault());

    return (from r in groupedRevisions 
            orderby r.RevisionNumber
            select new RevisionDto
            {
               // other properties omitted for clarity
               UniqueId = r.UniqueId,
               RevisionNumber = r.RevisionNumber
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've cheated a little and used the `MaxBy` operator from [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
return revisions
        .GroupBy(r => r.UniqueID)
        .SelectMany(g => g.MaxBy(r => r.RevisionNumber))
        .Select(r => 
          new RevisionDto 
              {
                 UniqueId = r.UniqueId,
                 RevisionNumber = r.RevisionNumber
              })
        .OrderBy(r => r.RevisionNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using:

```
            var q = from r in revisions
                    group r by r.UniqueId into grouped
                    select new ReveisonDto
                    {
                        UniqueId = grouped.Key,
                        RevisionNumber = grouped.Max(x => x.RevisionNumber)
                    };
```

but obviously this wouldn't work if you actually wanted to get the original object rather than the Dto

Comment: He omitted other information he wants to use as well - that's where the problem is - LINQ lacks a `MaxBy` operator to get the object instead of just the value. That's why I used the one from morelinq.

Answer (score 0):

If you asking is there a way to combine the two queries, then here's a naive way to do it:

```
return from r in revisions
       orderby r.RevisionNumber descending
       group r by r.UniqueId
           into grp
       select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.RevisionNumber).FirstOrDefault() into groupedRevisions
       from r in groupedRevisions 
       orderby r.RevisionNumber
       select new RevisionDto
       {
           // other properties omitted for clarity
           UniqueId = r.UniqueId,
           RevisionNumber = r.RevisionNumber
       };
```

However I would just rewrite it this way:

```
return from r in revisions
       orderby r.RevisionNumber
       group r by r.UniqueId
           into grp
       let r = grp.Last()
       select new RevisionDto
       {
           // other properties omitted for clarity
           UniqueId = r.UniqueId,
           RevisionNumber = r.RevisionNumber
       };
```

You're bound to go through the whole collection any way so you might as well sort once and get the last item within the group.